# Pandas - Breaking a huge Dataframe into smaller chunks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe of a million rows. I am trying to break it up into small sized Dataframes of 1000 rows each. I am able to break this huge Dataframe into smaller chunks (of 1000 rows each) using the below code:

```
size = 1000
list_of_dfs = [df[i:i+size-1,:] for i in range(0, len(df),size)]
```

I am however unsure how to call each of these smaller Dataframes in a loop so that I can read the entire 1000 small Dataframes that have been created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output is list of `DataFrame`s, so you can loop them:

```
out = []
for df_small in list_of_dfs:
    print (df_small)
    #procesing...
    out.append(df_small)
```

Similar:

```
for i in range(0, len(df),size):
    df_small = df[i:i+size-1,:] 
    print (df_small)
```

If data are in csv is possible use `chunksize` parameter:

```
for df_small in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=size):
    print (df_small)
```

Comment: thank you for your response. What I am trying to do here is call each of these Dataframe and perform some action. I am trying to see if I can call each Dataframe by some name (variable). I am able to do so using `list_of_dfs[0]` and so on but I am not sure how many such dataframes exists. Hope I made my request clearer here.. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinNash - Not sure, there is not possible use loop and processing each DataFrame?

Comment: @KevinNash - If need aproach like `list_of_dfs[0], list_of_dfs[1], list_of_dfs[N]` then `N` is `N = len(list_of_dfs-1)`